# How to start a @Bean with custom parameters after an event had happened with spring for tests?

Tags: kotlin, javabeans, applicationcontext, testcontainers

I am working on adding RepositoryTests with TestContainers framework for a project that uses R2dbc and I am running into the following situation:

1 - On the main project I set `r2dbc` url (with port and hostname) on application.yaml file and spring data manages everything and things just work.

2 - On the Tests however, I am using TestContainers framework more specifically `DockerComposeContainer` which I use to create a mocked container using docker-`compose.test.yaml` file with the databases I need.

3 - This container creates a `port` number on the go I define a port number on my docker-compose file but the port number that `DockerComposeContainer` will provide me is random and changes everytime I run the tests, what makes having a static url on `application-test.yaml` not an option anymore.

So I need to dinamically create this bean `R2dbcEntityTemplate` at run time and only after the `DockerComposeContainer` will give me the port number. So my application can connect to the correct port and things should work as expected.

I tried to create this class:

```kotlin
    package com.wayfair.samworkgroupsservice.adapter

    import io.r2dbc.mssql.MssqlConnectionConfiguration
    import io.r2dbc.mssql.MssqlConnectionFactory
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConstructorArgumentValues
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.GenericBeanDefinition
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile
    import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.core.DefaultReactiveDataAccessStrategy
    import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.core.R2dbcEntityTemplate
    import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.dialect.SqlServerDialect
    import org.springframework.r2dbc.core.DatabaseClient
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
    
    @Component
    @Profile("test")
    class TemplateFactory(
        @Autowired val applicationContext: ApplicationContext
    ) {
        private val beanFactory = applicationContext.autowireCapableBeanFactory as BeanDefinitionRegistry
    
        fun registerTemplateBean(host: String, port: Int) {
            val beanDefinition = GenericBeanDefinition()
            beanDefinition.beanClass = R2dbcEntityTemplate::class.java
            val args = ConstructorArgumentValues()
            args.addIndexedArgumentValue(
                0,
                DatabaseClient.builder()
                    .connectionFactory(connectionFactory(host, port))
                    .bindMarkers(SqlServerDialect.INSTANCE.bindMarkersFactory)
                    .build()
            )
            args.addIndexedArgumentValue(1, DefaultReactiveDataAccessStrategy(SqlServerDialect.INSTANCE))
    
            beanDefinition.constructorArgumentValues = args
            beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition("R2dbcEntityTemplate", beanDefinition)
        }
    
    //    fun entityTemplate(host: String = "localhost", port: Int = 1435) =
    //        R2dbcEntityTemplate(
    //            DatabaseClient.builder()
    //                .connectionFactory(connectionFactory(host, port))
    //                .bindMarkers(SqlServerDialect.INSTANCE.bindMarkersFactory)
    //                .build(),
    //            DefaultReactiveDataAccessStrategy(SqlServerDialect.INSTANCE)
    //        )
    
        private fun connectionFactory(host: String, port: Int) =
            MssqlConnectionFactory(
                MssqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                    .host(host)
                    .port(port)
                    .username("sa")
                    .password("Password123@#?")
                    .build()
            )
    }
```

And this is how my db initiliser looks like:

```kotlin
    package com.wayfair.samworkgroupsservice.adapter.note

    import com.wayfair.samworkgroupsservice.adapter.DBInitializerInterface
    import com.wayfair.samworkgroupsservice.adapter.TemplateFactory
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
    import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.core.R2dbcEntityTemplate
    import org.testcontainers.containers.DockerComposeContainer
    import org.testcontainers.containers.wait.strategy.Wait
    import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container
    import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers
    import java.io.File
    
    @Testcontainers
    class NoteTagDBInitializer : DBInitializerInterface {
        @Autowired
        override lateinit var client: R2dbcEntityTemplate
    
        @Autowired
        lateinit var factory: TemplateFactory
    
        override val sqlScripts = listOf(
            "db/note/schema.sql",
            "db/note/reset.sql",
            "db/note/data.sql"
        )
    
        init {
            factory.registerTemplateBean(
                cont.getServiceHost("test-db-local_1", 1433),
                cont.getServicePort("test-db-local_1", 1433)
            )
        }
    
        companion object {
            @Container
            val cont: KDockerComposerContainer = KDockerComposerContainer("docker-compose.test.yml")
                .withExposedService(
                    "test-db-local_1", 1433,
                    Wait.forListeningPort()
                )
                .withLocalCompose(true)
                .also {
                    it.start()
                    val porttt = it.getServicePort("test-db-local_1", 1433)
                    print(porttt)
                }
    
            class KDockerComposerContainer(yamlFile: String) :
                DockerComposeContainer<KDockerComposerContainer>(File(yamlFile))
        }
    }
```

I am not getting errors when trying to start this template factory with no useful error message,
But to be honest I don't know anymore if am putting effort into the correct solution, does anyone have any insight on how to pull this off or if I am doing anything wrong here?

So to summarise for production app it is fine, it starts based off of the url on application.yaml file and that's it, but for tests I need something dinamic with ports that will change everytime.

Thank you in advance ))

Answer (score 0):

Spring already has a solution for your problem.
If you're using a quite recent Spring version (>= `5.2.5`), you should utilize `@DynamicPropertySource` in order to adjust your test configuration properties with a dynamic value of the container database port. Read [official spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-dynamic-property-sources) for more details and kotlin code examples.

If you're stuck with an older Spring version, the interface you need is `ApplicationContextInitializer`. See this [spring github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/24540) for a small example.